# Not able to delete folder from gui or terminal

Tags: command-line, nautilus, delete

"NvXhVL3Rue" this unknown folder got created automatically.

1. I am not able to change permission
2. Not able to delete from terminal it stucks need to hit ctrl+z
3. when i open folder its blank stuck at loading
4. tried from both normal and root nautilus but stuks at

   > `Prepaing to delete 3,20,865 files(360 MB's)`

that file count is still increasing. output of only `ll`

> `drwxrwxrwx  2 rnztx rnztx 360812544 Feb 22 01:03 NvXhVL3Rue/`
>   result of smart test !
>   [image]

Comment: shows up permissions of the directory... so if you do a `sudo rm -rf NvXhVL3Rue` the directory is not gone? do you get any errors?

Comment: it is just stuck, showing nowthing, cursor is blinking @next line start. do i need to hit Ctrl+z ?

Comment: It is Ctrl-c; ctrl-z suspends, does not kill the process.

Comment: It's over 3 million files. It's going to take a while for it to get deleted.

Comment: Do us a favour and using the livecd try the same (after waiting for a bit and if it does not work), also look for the disk utility on the dash and selecting the disk in question do a smart test please.

Comment: Also, where exactly is the directory? What's the full path of the folder? And what exactly is inside it? Folders don't just automatically pop up and start filling up for no reason.

Comment: @dobey yes, a loooong while --- especially if he has a rogue something creating files.

Comment: that dir is in my user home folder, that is created after i ran BleachBit, and not able to get what is inside that !

Comment: @Bruno please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem probably cause because of **BleachBit(root)**, because just previously I used that, and NON-REMOVABLE NvXhVL3Rue folder got created.

> Running a **"SMART data & self test"** from *DISK utility* for that partition helped to
>   delete that folder

Comment: Please --- try to extend the answer to be useful to other users. We have another case http://askubuntu.com/questions/427647/strange-folder-in-my-home-folder?lq=1 and a probable bug in BleachBit http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/forum/unremovable-folder-after-trying-wipe-free-space

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and a fix.  I installed xubuntu 14.04 lts yesterday.  Installed my favourite software and removed those i dont use.  I like to clean system to virgin state after doing fresh install so i used Bleachbit for speed.  After cleaning system i thought i would clean free space.  Ok set it to run, had an emergency to attend and left it running for a few hours, bad idea. Came home, bleachbit had crashed.  As above i was left with an unknown file  mYumMGqpB8.  Tried RM, SRM, delete, etc  without success.  Fired up using LiveCD tried everything and no success.

I then downloaded Bleachbit to liveCD.  Ran it in root, selected the file and it started to scan file,  Eventually after many hours ( i left Left it running all night) bleachbit finished and file removed,  the file was 660MB had 327,064, 0kb files within it. Lesson learned?  Do not use bleachbit in root and leave your machine unattended.