# An Unknown directory or file in my home directory

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, directory, home-directory

Today i noticed that in my home folder there is an unknown directory with the name `HZ5JZhA.V7`

I have not created this directory but when i tried to go in to its properties, it says it was created today and when i tried to view the size of this file no result came just says calculating.

I tried to delete it by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> nothing happened and then I tried `rm` command also nothing results.

Please instruct me how to get rid of this annoying file...

thanks in advance

Comment: Tell us what you installed recently. I am guessing bleachbit?  See if this is similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/427647/strange-folder-in-my-home-folder-after-a-failed-run-of-bleachbit There are more programs that do this though.

Comment: Well i did not install anything but I used bleachbit with deepscan and system option tick marked along with others. After sometime when it took too long a time to finish, I aborted it (yeah, in the middle of the bleachbit operation). thanks

Comment: At first I opened Bleahbit with root privileges but i didn't run it and then i opened it with non root privilege and aborted it half way.

Comment: Then that is your answer: it is bleachbit.

Comment: Yes, bleachbit...And thank you very much for helping me where to look for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the `rm -rf` command for nearly one hour the file is gone now.