# tmp file in root folder with large size/ very long name

Tags: filesystem, files

As the title, I have this file in root folder and I don't know what it is.
Can I safely remove it?

```
-rw-------  1 root root 925M lug 22 15:28 tmpTKb8nhN6ke4IJ bnWrrgcIz-iyhS8H5V BAqFJNM7B.inBl47bd2TO_4xQ nwDtZ9UL7LK jOZc7DjhEQBRuqQ Q9SY0hIlqGh.7Tt1zkIFTgd9cjDUv38OXO-01ouoaFA4ZfqxlEkUT8AEveVA7wZazcLqa4Jg4ywe3JVY-6WYUg8e_t_XH9AooVQFm_hteSzoQmEw3iyEGDFHXkQsY iwyQ0ZqLI3lEPhsvktp9-tzE..dDvL8snJt5Oe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of tries, I finally found the problem. When I run bleachbit as root, it automatically creates files with similar names. I don't know which kind of options cause this, I'm still investigating.

EDIT:
take a look at this
[Strange folder in my home folder after a failed run of BleachBit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427647/strange-folder-in-my-home-folder-after-a-failed-run-of-bleachbit)
and this
http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/forum/bleachbit-wipe-free-disk-space-doesnt-work

In short, it seems that it is a bug of the "Wipe free space" option of Bleachbit (as root) 1.0.
You can download the new version from their site
http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux

Answer (score 0):

If your question is really "Will deleting this file damage my system?" No, deleting the file won't damage your system. But we don't know anything about the services and data ON your system.

Do just a little more investigation first:

When was it saved? (in Italian, for example, 'lug 22' its almost 5 months ago)
Do you remember what big changes you wrought as root back then?
Do you remember if you might have created some backups?

Also, make another test:

Change the file's name.
If after a normal backup cycle and a reboot cycle, your still don't need that file, then you have additional data to base your decision upon.

Comment: sure it can't damage the system, but I don't know what kind of stuff created/depends on it. yeah, is 5 months ago and maybe it's when I upgraded the system to 14.04, but I'm not too sure about it.
I'm testing the renaming ...oh wait, there is another file with a similar name now created just today. wtf?!??! Just testing, but I think it's due to bleachbit.