# Is there a way to make sure my system will boot before I reboot? I just ran bleachbit

Tags: boot, apt, bleachbit

I just ran bleachbit as a regular user (not as root) and the progress bar at the top is stuck at "Please wait. Wiping free disk space. About 0 minutes remaining" and the entire bleachbit screen has been grey for about 5-10 minutes.

I checked APT autoclean, autoremove, and clean. I'm concerned because in the past when I ran these commands in the terminal as sudo my system wouldn't boot and I had to reinstall because I had no clue what happened or how to fix it.

Comment: Interesting question =)

Comment: which version of bleachbit? Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/427647/strange-folder-in-my-home-folder-after-a-failed-run-of-bleachbit  ---  you can end up with a disk very full. If you check my answer you can see comments by the bleachbit author too.

Comment: Bleachbit is pretty much useless, read the last 3/4 of the "wipe" man page to find out why. http://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not check whether a restart will be successful. If that would work, then you could also prevent a restart to avoid that a system can not be restarted. **;)**

Normally, however, every system can be repaired. This is Linux and not Windows.

And before you re-install your system the next time, ask a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Lol, indeed! In the back of my mind I was curious if it were possible to somehow make a copy of the current state of my computer and then try running it in a virtual machine application such as virtualbox to see if it will boot.

Comment: @JonDoe Interesting thought. Maybe cloning the partition using `dd` and running a VM from that? But this will not include all the actions that would be done during the shutdown, i.e. flushing all file system buffers and probably modifying some status files and deleting locks. And you would need a disk to clone the image to that is at least as big as the original. It will most probably not work, I guess.

Comment: @ByteCommander And the differences in the used graphics drivers? :)

Comment: Hm? Oh, yes. I assumed the clone would run in the same or equal machine like the original...

Comment: funny answer and a bit audacious ... " ... and before you re-install your system the next time, ask a question." how to know to put a question if installing or re-installing is as successful as it was before ?! ... ;o)

Comment: @dschinn1001 
I meant, he should ask, how to fix a system, before a re-install.

Comment: @A.B. - users should fix the questions before they think and write ...  :o)